# Sample from known function

Tags: sampling, inference

I am wondering how is it possible to not be able to sample from a function that is known. *E.g.* suppose the expression of $f(x)$ is known but we need to approximate it in order to sample from it, why can't we directly do this on $f$?

Comment: When you say function, are you talking about a probability distribution? Can you give an example where you couldn't sample from a known function and had to approximate it?

Comment: Are methodologies such as rejection sampling acceptable means of sampling from a known function (for purposes of your question)?

Comment: I think you are asking why we need to use methods like rejection sampling if we already know the Probability Density Function (PDF).  Simply because you have a PDF and know its exact formula doesn't mean you can generate independent random samples from it.  The PDF simply tells you that, given a value $x$, what is the probability of $x$, $P(X=x)$ but it doesn't tell you how to actually generate a representative, independent sample of the $x's$ so that, together, they appear to have come from from the PDF.  So using something like rejection sampling allows you to generate iid samples.